# Linking an existing database to Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have created a SQL Server database for my application (the ERD is shown here):

[image: MyPortal Entity Relationship Diagram]

This database has already been populated with data from the School MIS, and I wish to "link" it to the application using Entity Framework.

I have already added classes such as `Student`, `Staff` as model classes within the project.

It might also be worth noting that I intend to use the `Roles` feature within ASP.NET to implement access rights.

How can I link this database to Entity Framework, or should I use EF to generate one from code?

Comment: I think you might be looking for database first where you populate an EDMX from the existing database. Check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj206878(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: It's a question of how you want to maintain moving forward. [Code first with an existing database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620(v=vs.113).aspx) is an option. Reverse engineer your existing database, then modify via code first and migrations moving forward. EDMX is not supported in EF Core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I enabled migrations to EF Identity by running `enable-migrations` (which used the ApplicationDbContext).

I then followed the [Entity Framework Code First to an Existing Database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620(v=vs.113).aspx) method to add a second DbContext into the application and to generate model classes.

Finally, I changed the ApplicationDbContext so that it used the *existing database* in its connection string and so the ASP.NET Identity tables were created in the existing database.

This does mean that if I want to change the database model, I will need to delete migrations and repeat this process, but it is a working solution to the problem.

Thanks!